# Aws amplify Auth.updateUserAttributes() giving [vuex] mutation error

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I am using aws amplify with vuex in nuxt.
On calling Auth.updateUserAttributes() is giving me a successfull response but it's also gives me the,
[vuex] do not change vuex store state outside mutation handler, even though I am not doing any mutation

```
export default state = () =>({
user: {} 
//CognitoUser data
}) 

export default actions = {
async updateUserAttribute(_, data), {
var user = data.user
var params = data. params 
await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, 
params )
} 
}
```

This is not the exact same code I have written,
But I think the problem lies with the aws amplify trying to manipulate the user state where  CognitoUser is saved

Comment: Try cloning the `user` object before passing it to `updateUserAttribute`.